# Log of cost function converges to 0 and is extremely "noisy"

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, loss-functions, noise

I'm writing my very first NN algorithm to solve a regression problem. I have a signal I would like to use a NN to find its correlation with eight other signals (along the line as f = f(x1, x2,..., x8)).

However, I am running into a problem with the convergence and the cost function. Plotting the logarithm of the cost function vs iteration one can see that there is some kind of convergence in the beginning (log(cost) converges to 0). Along with this convergence there is something I'm not sure what it is appearing which looks like noise of some sort (see plot below). And due to the incredible amount of "noise" and the convergence of log(cost) -> 0 the model does not fit the data at all.

I am building my own NN in Matlab to learn how it all works. For backpropagation I am using the same equations showed in this [tutorial](https://sudeepraja.github.io/Neural/).

I am using:

- 8 inputs
- 1 output
- ReLu for hidden layer
- Linear for output
- Initiate weights and biases using random function
- Tried both mini batch (Small, medium and big chunks) AND Stochastic
  gradient descent
- Tried both MSE and MAE for the output
- Tried different number of hidden layers (1 through 10)
- Tried many different number of neurons per hidden (2 all the way up to 200)
- Tried learning rates from 0.9 to 1e-6
- Tried dynamic learning rate = 1/iteration
- with and without filtering my data through low pass filter before
  passing it through
- I randomize the order from the signal before I pass it through and
  not in a chronological order
- Number of data points approximately 3.5e6
- Tried learning through epochs (run the data through several times)

None of these things helps the model.

According to me looking around the web the error rate typically converges nicely to a much lower value than 0 without this weird looking "noise" in the error. This drives me nuts trying to debug this or at least find the reason for this happens! Does anyone have any clue on what could be the cause of this?

[image: log(MAE) versus iteration]

Comment: Reviewing individual scatterplots for each of the eight independent variables versus the dependent variable might reveal some obvious data transformation, such as log or exp, that can help in the data modeling.

Comment: I've tried that but nothing changed. It seams like the log of the cost function is converging to 0 but not my actual cost function.

Comment: I have done a "sanity check" by running the same point over and over and this does converge the log(cost) to far below 0 as I would expect it to do therefore my algorithm would be correct.